# Vue SFC - Wait for child's event to be emitted then the function end

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, vue-sfc

I have an async method in the parent component which opens a b-modal component inside the child component, I would like to wait until the `hide` event is emitted and the associated function ends in order to continue the execution of the function.

**Parent :**

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <b-button @click="modal_queue()">
            Open modal
        </b-modal>
        <child ref="myChild"></child>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        async modal_queue() {
            for(let i=0,i<2<i++) {
                await this.aFunction();
            }
        },
        async aFunction() {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                this.$refs.mychild.$refs.myModal.$on("hide",() => {
                    resolve();
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Child :**

```html
<template>
    <b-modal ref="myModal" @hide="hidden()">
    </b-modal>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        hidden() {
            // Something
        }
    }
}
```

So I would like to wait until the `Something` code ends in order to resolve my Promise.

How I could do that ? Is my code architecture bad ?
For the moment, I'm only waiting until the 'hide' event is emitted.

Comment: You should think about using events - the modal can emit `hide` event on your event bus and your parent component can subscribe to this event and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Just `$emit` some custom event (for example 'hiddenEnded') at the end of `hidden()` method. Instead of listening for 'hide' on modal, listen for 'hiddenEnded' on `Child`. And you probably want to use `$once` instead of `$on`...

Comment: @IVOGELOV Yeah the parent can subscribe to my custom event but the treatment must be done in the child component.
In this case I still have to wait until this event is emitted and the code is executed over there.

Comment: @MichalLevý It should actually work

Child :
`hidden() {  // Something; this.$emit("hiddenEnded") }`

Parent :
`async aFunction() { return new Promise(resolve => { this.$refs.mychild.$once("hiddenEnded",() => { resolve(); } }); }`

Thank you.

Comment: I think that you're over-complicating the situation. In the world of events, anyone can emit an event - e.g. the modal can emit an event when it closes. Also, anyone can subscribe for a particular event - in your case, both the parent and the child and any other component(s) can subscribe for this `hide` event. They do not even need to know who is emitting this event. If you need the parent component to do something when the modal closes - and then the child to do something AFTER that, then subscribe the parent to `hide` event and subscribe the child for `done` event emitted by the parent.